# How to append to a 2d slice

Tags: go, append, 2d, slice

I have data that is created rows by rows, 6 columns, I don't know the final number of rows in advance.

Currently i'm creating a 2D slice of 200x6 with all zeros and then i replace these zeros gradually with my data, row by row. The data comes from another dataframe df

It works but i don't like to end up with the last rows of my slice full of zeros. I see 2 solutions:
- I delete all the last rows with only zeros when I'm done
- I create an empty slice and append my data progressively to it

I tried various things but could not figure out how to code any of these 2 solutions.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var orders [200][6]float64  // create my 2d slice with zeros
order_line := 0

for i := start_line; i <= end_line; i++ {
    if sell_signal == "1" {
        //record line number and sold price in orders slice
        orders[order_line][1] =  float64(i+1)
        orders[order_line][2],err = strconv.ParseFloat(df[i][11], 64)
        order_line = order_line + 1
     }
}
```

I looked at the Append command, but I tried all sorts of combinations to make it work on a 2d slice, could not find one that works.

edit: from the comments below I understand that i'm actually creating an array, not a slice, and there is no way to append data to an array.

Comment: By specifying a size using `[number]` notation, you are not creating a slice, you are creating an array.

Comment: One question, why are you using arrays/slices for this in the first place? This seems more a job for a single dimensional slice full of structs that contain, and thus provide a name for, each of the fields instead of an index. That's better for readability, but again, it depends on __why__ you want/need to use arrays/slices.

Comment: oh crap, that explains why i'm struggling so much. But then, my problem remains, is there a way to append data to a 2D array ? or is it simpler to delete my zeros when i'm done ?

Comment: You cannot append or delete elements from an array because arrays are fixed size.  It sounds like a slice is more appropriate here.

Comment: Go has no 2D slices (or arrays as in your actual code). Only slices of slices, or arrays of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the outer container has an unknown number of elements and the inner container has exactly six elements, use a slice of arrays.

```
var orders [][6]float64
for i := start_line; i <= end_line; i++ {
    if sell_signal == "1" {
        n, err = strconv.ParseFloat(df[i][11], 64)
        if err != nil {
            // handle error
        }
        orders = append(orders, [6]float64{1: float64(i + 1), 2: n})
    }
}
```

This code uses a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) [6]float64 value instead of assigning element by element as in the question.

You can come back and access elements of the [6]float64 at a later time.  For example:

```
 orders[i][3] = orders[i][1] + orders[i][2]
```

Comment: with this method, can I append a row in 2 shots ? meaning i append the first 3 columns of a row, then do something else, then come back and complete the last 3 columns of that same row ?

Comment: I assumed that rows all contain 6 elements based on comments from other questions. Is that correct?   If so, there's no need to append more values with this answer.

Comment: Each row in this answer is a six element array.  The elements that are not explicitly set in the composite literal are initialized to zero. You can access the elements of the array at any time using an index expression like `orders[i][3]`.

Answer (score 6):

In Golang slices are preferred in place of arrays.

Creating so many rows in prior is not required, just create a slice every time you are looping over your data to add a new row in the parent slice. That will help you to have only required number of rows and you need to worry about the length Since you are appending a slice at an index of parent slice.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    orders := make([][]float64, 0) // create my 2d slice with zeros
    for i := 0; i <= 6; i++ {
        value := rand.Float64()
        temp := make([]float64, 0)
        temp = append(temp, value)
        orders = append(orders, [][]float64{temp}...)
    }
    fmt.Println(orders)
}
```

Please check working code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ReDIvH_l85b)

If you notice I am creating a new `temp` slice in loop which contains the `float64` value and then appending value to the temp slice which I have passed to the parent slice.

So everytime I append the temp slice to the parent slice a new row will be created.

**Note:**

> Arrays have their place, but they're a bit inflexible, so you don't
>   see them too often in Go code. Slices, though, are everywhere. They
>   build on arrays to provide great power and convenience.

**Edited:**

To work on first 3 columns and then manipulate the values for next 3 columns which will be added to the temp slice and appended to the main slice. Use below code logic:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    orders := make([][]float64, 0) // create my 2d slice with zeros
    for i := 0; i <= 6; i++ {
        value := rand.Float64()
        // logic to create first 3 columns
        temp := make([]float64, 0)
        temp = append(temp, value)

        temp2 := make([]float64, 3)

        // logic to create next 3 columns on basis of previous 3 columns
        for j, value := range temp {
            addcounter, _ := strconv.ParseFloat("1", 64)
            temp2[j] = value + addcounter
        }

        temp = append(temp, temp2...)
        orders = append(orders, [][]float64{temp}...)
    }
    fmt.Println(orders)
}
```

Working [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/4EiDI0aHwjf)

Comment: I like the note you added. If you use arrays specifically, you __must__ then write your own code that utilizes it. There is practically nothing in any library that natively utilizes arrays in their exported APIs.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear I am sorry but I did not get your point, the note that I have written is specific to golang. That's why you always see slices in places of arrays in libraries created for golang. Also Slice are much comfortable to use from developer point of view since you need not to worry about the length since it grows according to requirement using build in function append.

Comment: The point of my comment was Go uses slices everywhere, as such, if you write your code using arrays for some reason, you are going to have to continue to write your own code to use them. Nowhere else will be using them, so you can't simply pass them into another library. i.e. Don't use arrays.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear oh I get it. You are absolutely right in this case. Slices are used every where in place of arrays.

Comment: @Himanshu, the only thing i'm not sure of is: i have 6 columns, i compute the data for the first 3 columns, then, I compute some more data that depends on the first 3 columns to get to the last 3 columns. Can I append  the first 3 columns of a row first, then later on write the last 3 columns of that same row ? Or I can only append to a new row ?

Comment: @Hugues yes you can just create one more temp slice and append it to the first one temp slice and then append the whole slice to the parent slice.

Answer (score 1):

For better readability, and easier slice handling, just create a struct type and fill a slice with them. This allows you to properly name each field instead of magic index numbers and makes it easier to fill in the rows as well as utilize later. Unless there is some specific reason to use arrays/slices for the columns, this is more idiomatic Go. The following example would fill a slice with however many results you have, and no more.

Full example here: https://play.golang.org/p/mLtabqO8MNj

```
type Row struct {
    Thing   float64
    Data    float64
    More    float64
    Stuff   float64
    Another float64
    Number  float64
}

var rows []*Row

numResults := 15
for i := 0; i <= numResults; i++ {
    row := &Row{}
    row.Thing = 2.5
    // ... fill values
    rows = append(rows, row)
}
```

Comment: with this method, can I append a row in 2 shots ? meaning i append the first 3 columns of a row, then do something else, then come back and complete the last 3 columns ?

Comment: @Hugues yes. If the `row` struct is still in scope after "doing something else", you can just set the values. If not, you just need to know the index of the row you are working on and could access it that way, e.g. `rows[i].More = 1.1` You can `append` the `row` to the slice at any point in time and still modify it later by index too, if you wish.